# PHP strtotime() different between ('Wednesday') and ('next Wednesday')

Tags: php

The problem I'm having is in trying to look up wednesday of next week.

```
$next_wednesday = strtotime("next Wednesday 19:00:00"); 
$this_wednesday = strtotime("Wednesday 19:00:00");
```

The values for `$next_wednesday` and `$this_wednesday` come out the same

Comment: Technically the Wednesday coming up *is* the next Wednesday...

Comment: IMO people want to rely in `strtotime`'s automagic for too many cases. It has some very specific rules where "natural language parsing" like "next Wednesday" works, but it's not omniscient or an AI. Most of the time good old time math works better or is the only way to make it work.

Comment: You will only get different dates from that if "today" actually _is_ Wednesday.

Comment: What if the current day is Friday? Which Wednesday would you want to be getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$this_wednesday = strtotime("Wednesday 19:00:00");
$next_wednesday = strtotime("+1 week Wednesday 19:00:00");
```

Answer (score 2):

try using more specific texts when using strtotime.

```
$this_wednesday = strtotime('Wednesday this week 19:00:00');
$next_wednesday = strtotime('Wednesday next week 19:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$this_wednesday = strtotime("Wednesday 19:00:00");
$next_wednesday = strtotime('last Wednesday');

echo date('m/d/y h:i a',$this_wednesday) . "\n" . date('m/d/y h:i a',$next_wednesday);
```

See the [Demo](https://eval.in/35168)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $year = 2013;
    $month = 7;
    $day = 5;


    echo date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime('next Wednesday')).'<br>';

    echo date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime('next 

    Wednesday',mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year)));

   ?>
```